# Bind XAML property to arbitrary object from codebehind

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I feel like this should be easy, but I've spent the last several hours trying solutions for this and nothing seems to work.

I have an object in XAML code, and I want to bind one of its properties to an object that was created in the c# codebehind.  This is my strategy so far:

```
<setpwindows:ScalingWindow
    ...
>
    <setpwindows:ScalingWindow.Resources>
        <localwpf:ObjectProvider x:Key="locationProvider"/>
    </setpwindows:ScalingWindow.Resources>
    ...
        ...
            <DataGridTextColumn
                Header="Code Out"
                Binding="{Binding Source={StaticResource locationProvider}, Path=Obj.Name}"
            />
        ...
    ...
</setpwindows:ScalingWindow>
```

with ObjectProvider as follows:

```
class ObjectProvider : DependencyObject
{
    private object _obj;
    public object Obj
    {
        get { System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Got object as " + _obj); return _obj; }
        set { _obj = value; System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Set object to " + _obj); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ObjProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Obj", typeof(object), typeof(ObjectProvider));

    public ObjectProvider() {}
}
```

After the window is initialized, I set Obj like this:

```
WPFObjects.ObjectProvider locProv = this.FindResource("locationProvider") as WPFObjects.ObjectProvider;
locProv.Obj = _tempLocation;
```

This finally gives me no binding errors in the output window, but it doesn't actually bind anything.  What is the standard way of doing this?

Comment: You have to learn Dependency Properties and Binding from the scratch

Answer (score 3):

This is all kinds of wrong, here just a few pointers:

- dependency properties are targets of bindings, not sources.
- do you set Obj anywhere? Does that what you set have a name property?

Then, learn about **FrameworkElement.DataContext** and the notification interfaces you can implement to notify dependency properties about changes in your data sources. see in other people's code hiw e.g. ViewModels look like and how they are bound to the UI.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'm still just so confused.  I have seen countless examples and lessons (perhaps the wrong ones), but none of them seem to tell me how I can (1) create an object in c#, (2) pass it to XAML, and (3), bind an XAML object's property to a member of the c# object.  Especially for something like a DataGridTextColumn, which cannot take a DataContext parameter.  The reason I used a dependency property is because it gave me binding errors saying that I had to.  I do set Obj just after the window is initialized; I have now included the code above.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm barking up the wrong tree here.  My problem is not really with binding at all.  This was a really long path I went down to fix an error with datagrid text columns.  I will ask another question.